# To find kernel of given transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Question says "Let $T:R^3\to R^3$ be a projection onto P, where P is a plane through origin with normal vector $\vec{n}\neq \vec{0}$. Let $S:R^3 \to R^3$ be a reflection across L, where L is the line given by span$(\vec{v})$ with $\vec{v} \neq \vec{0}$, a vector in P." I needed to find kernel of $T\circ S$ and $S\circ T$.

My thought for $T\circ S$ is that $T$ will send the vectors along $\vec{n}$ to origin. But I am not sure how to find those vectors which will get mapped to scalar multiple of $\vec{n}$ by $S$. How to find them?

For $S\circ T$, I think kernel is precisely $\alpha \vec{n}$. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Kernel of $T \circ S$**

$x \in \ker T \circ S$ means $T(S(x))=0$, i.e. $S(x)$ collinear with $n$. It exists $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ such that $S(x) = \lambda n$. Now remember that a reflexion is an involution. So

$$x=(S \circ S)(x) = \lambda S(n)$$

Conclusion: $\ker T \circ S$ is the image under $S$ of the line orthogonal to $P$ passing through the origin.

**Kernel of $S \circ T$**

$S(T(x)) = 0$ implies that $T(x) = 0$ as $S$ is bijective. Hence the kernel is equal to the line normal to $P$ passing through the origin.